# Chrome extension - pop up box on page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, e-commerce

I am trying to develop a chrome extension that assists users for online shopping price comparison.

I just found one similar extension - [Makkhichoose](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/makkhichoose/gllmlkidgbagkcikijiljllpdloelocn?hl=en)

I just have to explain what Makkhichoose does to explain my question.

Now once the extension is installed and a user visit [Amazon](https://www.amazon.in/) / [Flipkart](https://www.flipkart.com/) and we reached a product listing page. And when the page load is completed. A small window is displayed with the lowest price for the same products across some mainstream e-commerce sites so that the user can know the lowest price.

Now I just what to know how can I just create a window that is draggable over a web page when the mouse has hovered above a specific image or button or div.

**I am not asking how to do the comparison. But how to generate a box or window popup on page load.**

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: This is a normal DOM element as you can see in devtools inspector, so to create it, use a content script.

Comment: If you actually want someone to do it for you we would need to know *exactly* what it is that you want. I suggest you ask a narrower question that is about the *first issue* that you are having trouble with. Break your problem into parts, ask about the parts in the order you need to tackle them. It's probably a good idea to wait for answers, as the answers may lead you in other directions.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).